# How to set Data Tables column visibility in a specific table

Tags: jquery, datatables

("Data Tables refers to the jQuery [Data Tables](https://datatables.net/) product.)

In this scenario, I need to selectively show or hide columns of a specific table (out of three tables) on a specific page.  When I run this script, I get a jQuery console error `Cannot read property 'bVisible' of undefined`.

The existing forum answers relate to the correct spelling of `.DataTable()`. That is not the issue here.

According to the existing [documentation](https://datatables.net/reference/api/table()), I am correctly defining `oTable`, but perhaps the documentation assumes I have only one table on the page (I have three). Is there something I should do so that the table is correctly defined?

```
function setVisibleColumnsAverage() {
    $("#LoadingMessage").modal("show");
    var headers = ["Not Rated", "Target", "Ongoing", "Complete"];    
    var status = $("#InterventionStatus").val();

    //  Below is the relevant Data Table code

    var oTable = $(".display").DataTable();

    for (var j = 0; j < status.length; j++) {
        for (var i = 0; i < headers.length; i++) {
            if (status[j] === "Not Rated" && headers[i] === "Not Rated") {
                oTable.table("#InterventionAverage").column(4).visible(true, false);
                oTable.table("#InterventionAverage").column(9).visible(true, false);
            }
            if (status[j] === "Target" && headers[i] === "Target") {
                oTable.table("#InterventionAverage").column(5).visible(true, false);
                oTable.table("#InterventionAverage").column(10).visible(true, false);
            }
            if (status[j] === "Ongoing" && headers[i] === "Ongoing") {
                oTable.table("#InterventionAverage").column(6).visible(true, false);
                oTable.table("#InterventionAverage").column(11).visible(true, false);
            }
            if (status[j] === "Complete" && headers[i] === "Complete") {
                oTable.table("#InterventionAverage").column(7).visible(true, false);
                oTable.table("#InterventionAverage").column(12).visible(true, false);
            }
        }
    }

    oTable.columns.adjust().draw(false);
}
```

I have tried other variations with the same result, such as:

```
var oTable = $(".display").DataTable();
var table1 = oTable.table("#InterventionAverage");

for (var j = 0; j < status.length; j++) {
    for (var i = 0; i < headers.length; i++) {
        if (status[j] === "Not Rated" && headers[i] === "Not Rated") {
            table1.column(4).visible(true, false);
            table1.column(9).visible(true, false);
        }
        if (status[j] === "Target" && headers[i] === "Target") {
            table1.column(5).visible(true, false);
            table1.column(10).visible(true, false);
        }
        if (status[j] === "Ongoing" && headers[i] === "Ongoing") {
            table1.column(6).visible(true, false);
            table1.column(11).visible(true, false);
        }
        if (status[j] === "Complete" && headers[i] === "Complete") {
            table1.column(7).visible(true, false);
            table1.column(12).visible(true, false);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out that the error message `Cannot read property 'bVisible' of undefined` was a hint that one of the column numbers was out of range. Although I had counted columns on the rendered html page, I failed to take into account that the column numbers started with 0 and not 1. After this adjustment, none of the columns were out of range and the code operated correctly.